# How to figure out which class to use in Spring?

Tags: spring

I have some code that parses a text data into Java objects. There are several parsers available based on a json value. e.g. when type=1, use parser1, type=2 use parser2 etc.

My code is like the following:

```
interface Parser {
    Data parse(Input data);
}

class Parser1 implements Parser {
}

class Parser2 implements Parser {
}


switch(type)
{
   case 1:
     return parser1.parse(data);
   case 2:
     return parser2.parse(data);
   default:
     return null;
}
```

I don't like manually check type and manually select parser. Is there a way to let spring handle the mapping from type to parser?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't avoid the check for mapping, you will have to tell spring in one way or the other what parser to choose in each state.

You can implement it very nicely using a ParserFactory that will have one getParser method.
For example:

```
public class ParserFactory {

@Autowire
@Qualifier("parser1")
Parser parser1;

@Autowire
@Qualifier("parser2")
Parser parser2;

public static Parser getParser(String value){
    if(value.equals("x")){
        return parser1;
    }else if (value.equals("y")){
        return parser2;
    }
}
}
```

If you like you can have a list of Parser and configure it with @Resource annotaion.

You can instantiate your parser using the spring config xml:

```
<bean id="parser1" class="com.myCompany.parsers.Parser1"/>
<bean id="parser2" class="com.myCompany.parsers.Parser2"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

i am not 100% sure as i have never tried this but you can have a look for runtime dependency injection using AOP.

[Spring AOP and dependency injection](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable)